# Expand pandas column based on the cell type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
  field          value
0 longitude      100
1 altitude       200
2 location       China
3 date           20180303
......
```

I want to convert this dataframe into the following format:

```
   field      string_value int_value datetime_value boolean_value float_value field_type
0  longitude  NA           NA        NA             NA            100         float
1  altitude   NA           NA        NA             NA            200         float
2  location   China        NA        NA             NA            NA          str
3  date       NA           NA        20180303       NA            NA          datetime
......
```

How could I efficiently do this? I think I can do this with `apply` but that seems slow because its going through the dataframe row by row. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What is `print (df['value'].head().apply(type))` ?

Comment: Something like: ```0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2      <class 'str'>
3    <class 'datetime'>
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is get `type`s of values, convert to string and `map` to better readable form, then for new columns use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
d = {'field': ['longitude', 'altitude', 'location', 'date','check'], 
     'value': [100, 200.5, 'China', pd.Timestamp('20180303'), True]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#print (df)

d = {"<class 'bool'>":"bool",
     "<class 'float'>":"float",
     "<class 'int'>":"int",
     "<class 'str'>":"string",
     "<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>":"datetime"}
s = df['value'].apply(type).astype(str).map(d).fillna('not defined type')
df = df.join(df.set_index(s, append=True)['value'].unstack())
df['field_type'] = s
print (df)
       field                value  bool             datetime  float  int  \
0  longitude                  100   NaN                  NaN    NaN  100   
1   altitude                200.5   NaN                  NaN  200.5  NaN   
2   location                China   NaN                  NaN    NaN  NaN   
3       date  2018-03-03 00:00:00   NaN  2018-03-03 00:00:00    NaN  NaN   
4      check                 True  True                  NaN    NaN  NaN   

  string field_type  
0    NaN        int  
1    NaN      float  
2  China     string  
3    NaN   datetime  
4    NaN       bool
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the most efficient way of handling this is creating a new column that stores the type of each element in ['value'] and then using pandas.pivot_table() with index = ['field'], values = ['value'] and columns being the column used to store the dtypes.

Comment: Have you tried this? I got DataError saying `No numeric types to aggregate`

Comment: There is some strings so `pivot_table` finds it hard to actually aggregate the values.

Comment: True, sorry! Use jezrael's answer instead.